# Excel 2013 Change color of a cell depending on the value in the cell

Tags: excel

Excel 2013.  If the value in cell C1 is less than 1, I would like the background to be yellow.  If the value is between 1 and 4, I want the background to be green.  If the value is greater than 4, I want the background to be red.  I have tried conditional formatting and cannot get it to work.

Comment: Google it please... https://superuser.com/questions/625597/changing-a-rows-color-depending-on-the-value-text-of-a-cell

Comment: The order you apply the conditional formatting is critical, first test for >4 then >1 and finally <1 .

Comment: Thank you Solar Mike.  I will try that tomorrow